# C++ : initialization, climits & variables

Tags: c++, initialization, limit

Disclaimer, new to programming, working my way through C++ Prime Plus 6th ed.

I'm working though listing 3.1.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <climits>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int n_int = INT_MAX;
    cout << "int is " << sizeof n_int << " bytes." << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

So I get, that creates a variable sets the max int value.

However, is there any reason why I should not and can't go:

```
cout << "int is " << sizeof (INT_MAX) << " bytes." << endl;
```

As it gives the correct length. But when I try with (`SHRT_MAX`) it returns 4 bytes, when I'd hoped it would return 2.

Again with (`LLONG_MAX`) it returns correctly 8 bytes, however (`LONG_MAX`) incorrectly returns 8.

Any clarification would be great.

Comment: What is the value of `SHRT_MAX` on your computer?

Comment: There are no short literals ;)

Comment: Just forget about silly `<climits>` and use [`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values defined in `<climits>` are macros that expand to integer literals. The type of an integer literal is the smallest integer type that can hold the value, but no smaller than `int`.

So `INT_MAX` will have type `int`, and so `sizeof INT_MAX` is the same as `sizeof (int)`. However, `SHRT_MAX` will also have type `int`, and so `sizeof SHRT_MAX` will not necessarily equal `sizeof (short)`.